# Ubuntu IOException creating directories

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ubuntu-13.10

Ok i am running a webapp in eclipse using tomcat6.
The problem is the application needs to create a subfolder in opt/resources.
When i run :

```
  new File("/opt/resources"+resource_name).mkdir();
```

then

```
 new File("/opt/resources"+resource_name+'img/').mkdir();
```

I get an ioexception :error creating directories

when i run only

```
  new File("/opt/resources"+resource_name).mkdir();
```

I get no errors but folder is not created, this only happens in ubuntu

I tried changing the owner of /opt/resources to tomcat and 777 none worked.

Comment: If you use sudo to switch to the tomcat user, can you manually create the directories then?

Comment: actually i havent tried that, but even when i started tomcat as root it still did not resolve the issue

Comment: Does `resource_name` begin with a `/`? Otherwise you do not try to create a subfolder of `/opt/resources` but rather a subfolder of `/opt` named `"resources"+resource_name` due to the missing `/`

Comment: yes it does, its strange i cant figure it out

Comment: It is as Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen suggested it was a user issue, it turns out only the user i am logged on as can see the /opt/ folder i created, as i created the subfolders logged in as default. So i changed it from tomcat6 to christopher in etc/init.d/tomcat6 and it worked. I guess will have to change to tomcat6 user from terminal and create root file and etc. Thanks again, any suggestions are welcomed.I apologize for lack of knowledge I am new to ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

`new File("/opt/whatever")` does not create directories.

`new File("/opt/whatever").mkdir()` does

Comment: I apologize i omitted that part from the description,new File("/opt/whatever").mkdir() does not work for me or does new File("/opt/whatever").mkdirs()

Comment: Don't do that. As you do not know what the problem is, you may not be able to judge what part of the code is irrelevant to your problem.  Please see http://sscce.org/